# JPA OneToMany with Parent composite pk is part of child primary key Derived Entity issue

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, composite

**One To Many with Parent composite primary key is part of child primary key issue. Throwing Exceptions with the below code snippets**

Sample JSON Embedded Data as follows:

{
"pt_reg_no": "1000",    //Serial number generation 
"game_year": "G12021",
"name": "myname",
"eventDetails": [{
"major_event_code": "A",
"sub_event_code": "A7",
"category_code": "MO"
},
{
"major_event_code": "B",
"sub_event_code": "B7",
"category_code": "WO"
}
]
}

Participant can register for multiple Events:
Participant (Composite Key) - pt_reg_no, game_year
EventDetails (Composite Key) - pt_reg_no, game_year, sub_event_code, category_code

```
//Parent Class IDclass
public class ParticipantKey implements Serializable {

    private Long pt_reg_no;
    private String game_year;
}

@IdClass(ParticipantKey.class)
public class ParticipantModel { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "participantseq"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "participantseq",
        allocationSize = 1
    )
    private Long pt_reg_no;
    
    @Id
    private String game_year = 'G12021';
    
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "participantModel", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<EventDetailsModel> eventDetails = new HashSet<>(); 

    public Set<EventDetailsModel> getEventDetails() {
        return eventDetails;
    }   
    public void setEventDetails(Set<EventDetailsModel> eventDetails) {
        this.eventDetails = eventDetails;

        for (EventDetailsModel b : eventDetails) {
            b.setParticipantModel(this);
        }
    }
    
}
    
//Child class IDclass    
public class ParticipantEventDetailsId implements Serializable {
        private ParticipantKey participantModel;
        private String sub_event_code;
        private String category_code;
    }
    
public class EventDetailsModel { 
      @Id    
      @Column(name = "sub_event_code")
      private String sub_event_code;
        
      @Id
      @Column(name = "category_code")
      private String category_code;
        
      @Id
      @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      @JoinColumns({
         @JoinColumn(name = "pt_reg_no", referencedColumnName = "pt_reg_no"),
          @JoinColumn(name = "game_year", referencedColumnName = "game_year")
      })
      private ParticipantModel participantModel;


    public ParticipantModel getParticipantModel() {
        return participantModel;
    }
    public void setParticipantModel(ParticipantModel participantModel) {
        this.participantModel = participantModel;
    }
    }
    
//---------------------------------------------------
//JSON input data received into ParticipantModel from @requestBody
public class FormDataObjects {
    private ParticipantModel formData;

    @JsonCreator
    public FormDataObjects(ParticipantModel formData) {
        this.formData = formData;
    }
}

//Controller Entry point
@RequestMapping(path = "/participantData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<?> participantRegistration(@Valid @RequestBody FormDataObjects values) {
        ParticipantModel participant = values.getFormData();
        participant.setGame_year(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(new Date()) + GenricData.game);
     
        ParticipantModel person = participantRepository.save(participant);
        
                if (person == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Participant is not inserted");
        } else {
            Set<EventDetailsModel> eventDetails = participant.getEventDetails();
            if (eventDetails.size() > 0) {
                eventDetails.forEach(event -> {
                    
                    //event.setPt_reg_no(person.getPt_reg_no());
                    //event.setGame_year(person.getGame_year());
                    //event.setParticipantModel(participant);
                    entityManager.persist(event);
                    entityManager.flush();
                    entityManager.clear();
                });

            }

        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok("inserted");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution to OneToMany mapping **when** parent has composite key and serial number generation is also required at parent

**Use @Transient annotation at Set or List Child Entities**
1)save Parent entity with above annotation helps jpa to skip List/Set of EventsDetailsModel from saving 
2) Iterate Child and get Parent composite key values which are already saved and persist child data along with childs key attributes.

```
//Parent Class IDclass
public class ParticipantKey implements Serializable {

    private Long pt_reg_no;
    private String game_year;
}

@IdClass(ParticipantKey.class)
public class ParticipantModel { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "participantseq"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "participantseq",
        allocationSize = 1
    )
    private Long pt_reg_no;
    
    @Id
    private String game_year = 'G12021';
    
    @Transient  //Find exact path for Transient
    private Set<EventDetailsModel> eventDetails = new HashSet<>(); 

    public Set<EventDetailsModel> getEventDetails() {
        return eventDetails;
    }   

    
}
    
//Child class IDclass    
public class ParticipantEventDetailsId implements Serializable {
        private Long pt_reg_no;
        private String game_year;
        private String sub_event_code;
        private String category_code;
    }
    
public class EventDetailsModel { 
      @Id    
      @Column(name = "sub_event_code")
      private String sub_event_code;
        
      @Id
      @Column(name = "category_code")
      private String category_code;
        
      @Id
      private Long pt_reg_no;

      @Id
      private String game_year;
  
    }
    
//---------------------------------------------------
//JSON input data received into ParticipantModel from @requestBody
public class FormDataObjects {
    private ParticipantModel formData;

    @JsonCreator
    public FormDataObjects(ParticipantModel formData) {
        this.formData = formData;
    }
}

//Controller Entry point
@RequestMapping(path = "/participantData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<?> participantRegistration(@Valid @RequestBody FormDataObjects values) {
        ParticipantModel participant = values.getFormData();
        participant.setGame_year(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(new Date()) + GenricData.game);
     
        ParticipantModel person = participantRepository.save(participant);
        
                if (person == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Participant is not inserted");
        } else {
            Set<EventDetailsModel> eventDetails = participant.getEventDetails();
            if (eventDetails.size() > 0) {
                eventDetails.forEach(event -> {
                    
                    event.setPt_reg_no(person.getPt_reg_no());
                    event.setGame_year(person.getGame_year());
                    entityManager.persist(event);
                    entityManager.flush();
                    entityManager.clear();
                });

            }

        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok("inserted");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a "derived identity" by mapping your details class like this:

```
public class ParticipantEventDetailsId implements Serializable {
    private String sub_event_code;
    private String category_code;
    private ParticipantKey participantModel; // matches name of attribute and type of ParticipantModel PK
}
    
public class EventDetailsModel { 

    @Id
    @Column(name = "sub_event_code")
    private String sub_event_code;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "category_code")
    private String category_code;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "pt_reg_no", referencedColumnName = "pt_reg_no"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "game_year", referencedColumnName = "game_year")
    })
    private ParticipantModel participantModel;

}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.

Comment: ParticipantModel [pt_reg_no=1000, game_year=G12021,name=bapuji, eventDetails=[EventDetailsModel [major_event_code=A, state_abbr=null, sub_event_code=A7 , category_code=MO ]]]                                                                              
 Thank you  @Brian getting below exception                                                                                                                                        **Nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No part of a composite identifier may be null] with root cause**

Comment: @BapujiNakka, it might be that the participant details returned by your call to `participant.getEventDetails()` do not contain backpointers to the ParticipantModel (i.e. `EventDetilasModel.participantModel` is `null`).

Comment: Yes @Brian it is null only as shown here:- ParticipantModel [pt_reg_no=null, game_year=202126, name=Bapuji, eventDetails=[EventDetailsModel [major_event_code=A, state_abbr=null, sub_event_code=A7 , category_code=MO , participantModel=null]]] **1)how to set backpointer to parent. updated getters and setters in my question ABOVE . can you please see what is wrong. 2) pt_reg_no serial number in parent also not getting generated due to some conflict**